# Ubuntu: downgrade SDL2 version

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to run a python graphical application made with KIVY framework, then I have this on my terminal:

```
root@MZs83nQ1:/home/kruqer/Documents/mybackup/Appoff# python appoff.py 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-11-09_5.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) 
[GCC 7.2.0]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "appoff.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 319, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 30, in <module>
     from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/event.py", line 8, in <module>
     import kivy._event
 ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/_event.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

I made researches on google and I found [this topic](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5453) and I need to downgrade my sdl2 version to a version between 2.0.5 and 2.0.6, but I can't see which version am I running actually and don't know how to downgrade it. 
My OS is Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 0):

## Display SDL Version

Execute the following and it will show you the SDL version that you are using:

```
dpkg -l | grep sdl
```

## Uninstall

```
sudo apt-get remove package1 [package2 ...]
```

## Install

### Python 2.x/3.x

```
sudo apt-get install -y \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev
```

## Example - OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64bits), Python 2.x

[image]

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libsdl3-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsdl3-image-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsdl3-mixer-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsdl3-ttf-dev

Comment: And which packages precisely have I to remove ?

Comment: @Mike Delta, all listed in the second column with sdl2 in their name, for example: sudo apt-get remove libsdl2-2.0.0